# Javascript: get <img> src and set as return "" address?

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
function getFavicon(){
     return "http://example.png"
}
```

This code is the only one that works for me. When I try to change the url within that to a code like " return `"chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0]""` it shows nothing...
can someone please help me?

Comment: what is the value of `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0]` ?

Comment: Is this a question about Chrome extensions?

Comment: try `return chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0];` - note the lack of any " or '

Comment: Yes, it's about chrome extensions. The value of that line is to get the first image on the page.

Comment: Connexo, I've tried that! Doesn't work :( I need it in a return "" format...I'm just not sure how to declare it FML

Comment: Can someone please help me? Jaromanda X that doesn't work. I've tried it. I'm not sure why it's not working. Whenever I switch it from a literal url to a code without quotations, my popup.htm won't even RUN it :( can someone help? fml

Comment: @MaxGillard what do you mean by it does't work ..? are you sure you are not getting any error ?? and didn't you try to print `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0]` ?

Comment: Fast Snail I'm not sure how to print ? :( I want the image to show in the popup.htm but it literally won't show unless it's in quotations. i just dont understand. it would literally be the world if you can help. ill answer anything and take pictures ? anything! :( please help

Comment: I've been working on this problem for 3 days straight and to no avail fml.

Comment: basically if i try to run it with the chrome.extension() etc it will never show anything. if i set it to return a random .png it will work.. im just like wtf. So how can i return the background first img src to a return address? Can someone please enlighten me? take your time but please help!

Comment: @MaxGillard there can be lot of reason for this.first try to print '' using console.log .and  you first need to know how to debug your code .so if there is a error you can see it and you can print `..imageSrc[0]` and see the actual value .for example may be `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` is null  or it return empty String.where do you show the image? you can view source and see what is inside src tag .it should be invalid src or ...

Comment: please fast snail please help me. I dont know how to do that. Look please im so desperate:( please. the backgroundpage works on another extension but not this one so im not sure how to do the console.log :( im just running on a macbook air i dont have that much programming knowledge. if you cant help, can you tell me someone who can? please fml

Comment: @MaxGillard, you're not making it easy to help you. Where's the relevant code of the background script where imageSrc is defined and assigned? Edit your question and add it.

Comment: @wOxxOm the task is a bit daunting considering there are two distinct (and long) background scripts. also both popups are differnt one is htm one is html if that helps?

Comment: No. That's not helpful at all. The *relevant* code would be helpful and you should have added it right from the start.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tyRPkJlJNn

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
function backgroundFunction () {
    return "http://example.png" 
}

(function () {
    var otherWindows = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    console.log(otherWindows.backgroundFunction()); 
})();
```

Comment: Hi, I think we're closer with this one. At least my pop up will show the shape of an image. However, the actual image won't show . Just an x at the top right corner, as if the image is invalid. Do I need to add anything to your code?

Comment: thank you nontoxice for your help and everyone ! ily please keep trying im trying everything i can...

Comment: this code must be entered by dividing the respective elsewhere